# Microsoft Excel, how to hyperlink distinct items in a list

Tags: excel, hyperlink, formula

I have a long list of file path names that I'd like to turn into links to the files themselves.  The name of the links should be the same as the URLs.  Here's a reduced version of the data that I'm working with (my actual list runs into the thousands) -

A1 W:\99 Project\disc labels\45rpm\Ho Brah\scans\bakashakbrah.png

A2 W:\99 Project\disc labels\45rpm\Ho Brah\scans\tintopeepee.png

A3 W:\99 Project\disc labels\45rpm\Ho Brah\scans\puntani.png

I'd want this list to look as follows (bold means linked):

A1 **W:\99 Project\disc labels\45rpm\Ho Brah\scans\bakashakbrah.png**

A2 **W:\99 Project\disc labels\45rpm\Ho Brah\scans\tintopeepee.png**

A3 **W:\99 Project\disc labels\45rpm\Ho Brah\scans\puntani.png**

Any ideas.  Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A formula as straightforwards as:

```
=HYPERLINK(A1)
```

will make the link but whether that opens .png files may depend upon your set up.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do this with formulas. You could use this bit of VBA to do the trick (just put it in as a button's Click macro or something):

```
Dim i
i = 1 'replace with whatever line you're starting on
Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) 'replace 1 with the column you are using (also below)
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1)), _
        Address:=CStr(Cells(i, 1)), _
        TextToDisplay:=CStr(Cells(i, 1))
    End With
i = i + 1
Loop
```